# Unsupported operand error for datetime values

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting the following error when running the code below:

```
prev_suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) - 2))
      8 elif cq == '1':
----> 9     prev_suffix = ('_' + current_year -1 + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) + 2))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

Not entirely sure why this is not working

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()
current_year = str(x.year)[2:]
current_quarter = str(((x.month-1)//3)+1)
current_suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + current_quarter)

if current_quarter == '3':
        prev_suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) - 2))
elif cq == '1':
    prev_suffix = ('_' + current_year -1 + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) + 2))
```

Comment: where is the error? what line?

Comment: Give us the error short or text.

Comment: sorry just added them in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of

```
current_year -1
```

It should be

```
str(int(current_year) - 1))
```

This being the final version:

```
x = datetime.datetime.now()

current_year = str(x.year)[2:]
current_quarter = str(((x.month-1)//3)+1)
current_suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + current_quarter)

if current_quarter == '3':
        prev_suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) - 2))
elif current_quarter == '1':
    print(type(current_year), type(current_quarter))
    prev_suffix = ('_' + str(int(current_year) - 1) + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) + 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in line  `prev_suffix = ('_' + current_year + '_q' + str(int(current_quarter) - 2))`

**You try to add and subtract from string**

`current_year` type is a string and you try to subtract 1 from `current_year -1`

You can do this like this

```py
str(int(current_year) -1)
```